# graph layout using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I am currently working on a GUI with AngularJS, which contains a graph given with it's nodes and connections in a javascript objects like this:

```
Nodes = [{'name': 'name1', x: 0, y: 0, id: 1}, {'name': 'name2', x: 0, y: 0, id: 2}, {'name': 'name3', x: 0, y: 0, id: 3}];
Connections = [{'from': 1, 'to': 2}, {'from': 1, 'to': 3}];
```

What I need to do, is give the x and y values for every node. At the moment I am using a simple offset to avoid overlapping and render node-by-node, but I would like to calculate x and y values for each node to have a proper layout.

Is there an algorithm, that I give my nodes and connections to and returns with a layout (x, y values for every node), which is better looking than my simple solution?

I have tried D3, but I am already using a third party library for the graph and it's hard to integrate it, so a optimal solution would be to simply give the coordinates for the current library's data structure (Nodes and Connections).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [D3.js Force directed layout](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045) you can find such an algorithm. If you leave out the drawing code, you end up with the following:

```
var width = 100;
var height = 100;
var Nodes = [{'name': 'name1', x: 0, y: 0, id: 1}, {'name': 'name2', x: 0, y: 0, id: 2}, {'name': 'name3', x: 0, y: 0, id: 3}];
var Connections = [{'source': 1, 'target': 2}, {'source': 1, 'target': 3}];

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

simulation
    .nodes(Nodes);

simulation.force("link")
    .links(Connections);

console.log(Nodes, Connections);
```

If you now open your console and inspect the Nodes variable, you will see the x and y positions are updated.